# Toggle decorations for a window from the shell?

Tags: shell, x11

Is there a way to toggle X11 window decorations for a single window, given the window's ID, from a script?  If the answer to this question is window manager specific, I'm using openbox.

I thought xdotool could do this with:

```
xdotool ID alt+space d
```

or

```
xdotool ID alt+space; sleep 1; xdotool ID d
```

The popup does appear but something is typed into my shell rather than into the popup.

Answer (score 3):

you could set a keystroke for that in the openbox config ~/.config/openbox/${config}.xml in the `<keyboard>` section like this:

```
 <keybind key="C-S-d">
   <action name="ToggleDecorations"/>
 </keybind>
```

..to have decorations toggled by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-d in almost any application.

I've made 'em toggled by the maximize/shade function automatically when double-clicking the titlebar by adding `<action name="ToggleDecorations"/>` to the `<mousebind button="Left" action="DoubleClick">` part of the `<context name="Titlebar">` section like this:

```
<mousebind button="Left" action="DoubleClick">
  <action name="ToggleDecorations"></action>
  <action name="ToggleMaximize"/>
</mousebind>
```

so windows are decorized only as I need 'em to be. hope it helps even if the question is years old...

regards

Answer (score 2):

Finally got something close to what I want.  Example:

```
xdotool key -windowid 0x1200016 alt+space; sleep 1; xdotool key -windowid 0x1200016 End Up Return
```

The End moves the cursor to the last item in the popup menu.
The Up moves the cursor up one entry in the popup menu where the "Un/Decorate" item lives.
The Return simulates the press of the Enter key.

However, I still get something typed into the window being un/decorated.

If I try this:

```
xdotool key -windowid 0x1200016 alt+space End Up Return
```

garbage is continuously "typed" into the window being un/decorated and hides my mouse cursor until I press Control+c a few times.

Further, openbox fails to acknowledge keyboard presses and mouse clicks for a few seconds afterward.

Follow Up:
Sometimes xdotool and wmctrl cease to do anything.  This solution does not meet my needs.